# How to copy one integer array to another

Tags: c, memory-management

What is the best way to duplicate an integer array? I know `memcpy()` is one way to do it. Is there any function like `strdup()`?

Comment: `strdup` relies on a null terminator, which int arrays don't have. What's wrong with `memcpy`?

Comment: Ya that will do. I wanted know if I can do it in one go like the way it happens for strings using strdup().

Comment: Did you allocate the array with malloc, int x* = (int *) malloc(100) or just declare it  int x[100]; ??

Comment: @Chris: I got the point I have to write my own using `memcpy` as KSB suggested below.

Comment: @EvilTeach: I used malloc. I mean I would.

Comment: I will concur with Kerrek then.  <nag>  don't forget to free it when you are done </nag> :)

Comment: @EvilTeach: Sure. I promise. :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There isn't, and `strdup` isn't in the standard, either. You can of course just write your own:

```
int * intdup(int const * src, size_t len)
{
   int * p = malloc(len * sizeof(int));
   memcpy(p, src, len * sizeof(int));
   return p;
}
```

Comment: I would check if malloc returned NULL ;)

Comment: @KerrekSB, what should I pass to the `intdup` function. The first parameter is the variable to be copied, and the second?

Comment: @Identicon: Not quite; The first parameter is a pointer to the first element in your existing array of integers, and the second parameter is the number of elements that you want to copy (i.e. the size of the array or less). The first argument you pass needn't be a variable, it could also be some non-trivial expression, for example: `int a[100]={/*...*}; int * p = intdup(a + 25, 13);`

Answer (score 2):

This could work, if used properly:

```
#define arrayDup(DST,SRC,LEN) \
            { size_t TMPSZ = sizeof(*(SRC)) * (LEN); \
              if ( ((DST) = malloc(TMPSZ)) != NULL ) \
                memcpy((DST), (SRC), TMPSZ); }
```

Then you can do:

```
double dsrc[4] = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4 };
int *isrc = malloc(3*sizeof(int));
char *cdest;
int *idest;
double *ddest;
isrc[0] = 2; isrc[1] = 4; isrc[2] = 6;

arrayDup(cdest,"Hello",6); /* duplicate a string literal */
arrayDup(idest,isrc,3);    /* duplicate a malloc'ed array */
arrayDup(ddest,dsrc,4);    /* duplicate a regular array */
```

The caveats are:

- the `SRC` and `DST` macro parameters are evaluated more than once
- The type of the pointer/array passed as `SRC` must match that of the source array (no `void *` unless cast to the correct type)

On the other hand, it works whether the source array was `malloc()`ed or not, and for any type.