# How to copy an array

Tags: c

I have defined an array like this:

```
uint8_t brightnessvariants[4][101]={{1,2,...},{3,4,...},{5,6,...},{7,8,...}};
```

Now for my application i have to fill another array with one of the 4 arrays:

```
uint8_t brightnesstable[] = brightnessvariants[index][];
```

But that doesn't work. *Index* is counted from 0 to 3.

*brightnesstable* and *brightnessvariants* are defined in a header file as *extern*

How can I do it right?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: just use a loop to access the contents of the subarray and copy each value to the new array.

Comment: @johnelemans: What's wrong with `memcpy`?

Comment: nothing. I like using up cycles!

Comment: @EOF I had to modify my code and "brightnesstable" is integrated and it's working fine. I just don't want to change that running system :) I just need the modification now and will optimize my code later anyway. (It's a microcontroller application) I'll check if memcpy works.

Comment: Is `index` a fixed value, or is this code inside a function and you might create `brightnesstable` with different index from time to time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy one integer array to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287109/how-to-copy-one-integer-array-to-another)

Answer (score 1):

Simply do

```
 uint8_t brightnesstable[101]; 
 memcpy(brightnessstable, brightnessvariants[index], 101*sizeof(uint8_t));
```

`brightnessvariants[index]` is the address of the first item in the `(index+1)nth` row and the number of bytes you want to copy is 
`ROWSIZE*sizeof(ITEM_SIZE)`.

Comment: Suggest `memcpy(brightnessstable, brightnessvariants[index], sizeof brightnesstable);`

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you need to do. If you need to create separate storage for a duplication of one of the rows of `brightnessvariants`, then you can simply declare a separate array and copy the values as discussed in the comments and the other answer.

If, however, you simply need to access one of the rows of `brightnessvariants` in the current scope, then there is no need for separate storage and copying. All that is required is to declare a pointer and assign the starting address of the desired row. Then you can access the desired row of `brightnessvariants` as if it were a separate array. e.g.

```
uint8_t brightnessvariants[4][101] = {{0}}, *btable = NULL;
```

Above, `btable` (short for your `brightnesstable`) is simply a `uint8_t` pointer. It can be assigned the the address of any of the rows in `brightnessvariants`. e.g. for the second row

```
btable = brightnessvariants[1];
```

`btable` can then be used to access any value within the second row, just as if it were a separate array. Here is a short example that may help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main (void) {

    uint8_t brightnessvariants[4][101] = {{0}}, *btable = NULL;
    int nrows = sizeof brightnessvariants / sizeof *brightnessvariants;

    for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
        brightnessvariants[0][i] = i + 1;
        brightnessvariants[1][i] = i + 3;
        brightnessvariants[2][i] = i + 5;
        brightnessvariants[3][i] = i + 7;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
        printf ("\nbrightnesstable[%d] :\n\n", i);
        btable = brightnessvariants[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < 101; j++) {
            if (j && j % 10 == 0) putchar ('\n');
            printf (" %3hhu", btable[j]);
        }
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/ptrtobtable

brightnesstable[0] :

   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40
  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50
  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60
  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70
  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80
  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
 101

brightnesstable[1] :

   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22
  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32
  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42
  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52
  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62
  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72
  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82
  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92
  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102
 103

brightnesstable[2] :

   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14
  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34
  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44
  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54
  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64
  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74
  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84
  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94
  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104
 105

brightnesstable[3] :

   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16
  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26
  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46
  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56
  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66
  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76
  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86
  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96
  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106
 107
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any questions. If you need an example of copying instead of the use of a pointer, let me know and I'm happy to help.